# How do I fix the Controller Settings loosing the ELEMENT SHIFT WHEEL action?

Tags: controllers, magicka-2

The game involves accessing 8 Elements to cast spells. When you use a gamepad to play the game, the 8 elements are accessed by your four face buttons for the first four elements, then holding the L1 Bumper for the next four.

This 'shift' action also allows editing of the four MAGICKA quick slot spells.

Sometime last night while playing I lost this action. The remainder action, INTERACT, still works with the same button. The shift action is gone.

By gone I mean the game seems to have forgotten it exists. Rebinding it does nothing. It shows the STEAM key instead of whatever I bind it to. This problem continues using a gamepad, using a ps4 controller, after reinstalling magicka, after disabling and re-enabling both generic and ps4 controller options in steam, and after deleting and re-downloading the built in controller configs. I'm going to reinstall steam now after I post this.

Any other ideas?

Comment: It's been a long time guys, forgive me if I missed a format somewhere.